# Sourcing setup.bash in ROS2 foxy

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all. After installing ROS2 foxy in Ubuntu 20.04 from "fat' archive (binaries), when I try to source `/opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash`, ros2 is not recognized:

```
$ source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash
```

```
$ ros2
```

```
ros2: command not found
```

However, I can source `/ros2_foxy/ros2-linux/setup.bash`:

```
$ source ~/ros2_foxy/ros2-linux/setup.bash
```

```
$ ros2
```

```
usage: ros2 [-h] Call `ros2 <command> -h` for more detailed usage. ...
```

Is there any issues with my configuration? Or is foxy intended to be sourced only from `~/ros2_foxy/ros2-linux/setup.bash`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354809/sourcing-setup.bash-in-ros2-foxy/) by [hazevedosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/45539/hazevedosa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-06-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The directory `/opt/ros/foxy` comes from installing [Foxy from Debian packages](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Linux-Install-Debians/). If, instead, you installed [Foxy from the fat archive](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Linux-Install-Binary/), then sourcing the `setup.bash` file from the extracted location is all you should have to do. I.e. you don't have to `source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash`, instead `source ~/ros2_foxy/ros2-linux/setup.bash` is equivalent.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2020-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hazevedosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/45539/hazevedosa/) on 2020-06-15**:
Ok, but does that mean that the directory `/opt/ros/foxy` should not be present after my installation? Because it is there...

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2020-06-15**:
I wouldn't expect the directory `/opt/ros/foxy` to exist unless you installed a Foxy Debian package (e.g. `apt install ros-foxy-*`).